# How to get stepper and longpress to coexist?

Tags: ios, long-press, uistepper

I tried setting up a view with a longpress gesture and a stepper configured for continuous updates. With the longpress, the continuous feature of the stepper does not occur. For now, I've disabled the longpress. I guess I don't need it. But for future reference, how would I allow for both to coexist?

Just to be clear, here is the way the screen was set up when I tried this.

- App was set up with a simple view controller.
- A subview was added to this view (could have been a controller, but I just made it a UIView).
- Several labels and stepper were added to this subview.
- The steppers were wired up as outlets and actions.
- A longpress recognizer was added to the main view in IB.
- For completeness, a tap gesture was also added to the main view in IB.

Taps on the main view function as expected. Taps on the steppers function as expected. Longpress on the main view functions as expected. Longpress on the stepper does not.

I modified the code called by the longpress to check for the frame of the subview and not act if the touch location was within that rectangle, but that didn't make a difference. I did not try getting the longpress to fail in that situation, but I suppose I'll try that next. EDIT: OK, maybe not. There doesn't seem to be an API for that. However, there is [this kludge](http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2011/02/ios-cancelling-uigesturerecognizer.html), that I'm not going to try.

Attached is a screen shot from profiler with an inverted call tree so you can see what each item is being called by.

`darkStepped:` is the IBAction that is called by the stepper. If the stepper were triggered by a gesture recognizer, wouldn't I expect to see the gesture recognizer in the call tree?

[image: Screen shot of stepper showing section called by holding stepper]

Comment: please, provide some code so it is clearer what you are trying to do...

Comment: Not sure what kind of code to include. The stepper has no code other than an IBAction, which works with a tap, but not when holding. The longpress is a longpress gesture dragged in in IB. When I remove the longpress in IB, the stepper works in continuous mode. I don't think the issue is with my code but in knowing what sort of activity is going on behind the scenes with the stepper. For example, is the stepper using a longpress gesture recognizer that is conflicting with my view's longpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully reviewing Apple's docs again, I've found the solution. I added the view controller as the delegate to the longpress gesture recognizer

```
self.longPress.delegate = self;
```

(and, of course, adding `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` to the interface, and then added this method to the view controller:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
   // Determine if the touch is inside the custom subview
   if (gestureRecognizer == self.longPress) {
      CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.antControl.frame, touchLocation)) {
         return NO;
      }
   }
   return YES;
}
```

This way the gesture recognizer doesn't even get called when the longpress occurs within the frame of `self.antControl`, which is the subview mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> If the stepper were triggered by a gesture recognizer, wouldn't I expect to see the gesture recognizer in the call tree?

The stack trace reveals that the stepper's `_updateCount` method is dispatched through a timer.

This could be related to the fact that a stepper has an "autoIncrement" mode where, as long as your keep it pressed, it will update at a given (varying) rate. So, instead of simply calling `_updateCount`, the stepper sets up a timer to handle this behaviour.

For whatever reason the timer is used, the timer explains why you do not see the gesture recogniser in the stack trace.

In your case what happens is that the stepper gets the touches, handles them, and do not forward them to any gesture recognisers attached to it.

This can be explained as follows, although this snippet does not explicitly mention a long press recogniser in relation to a `UIStepper` control:

According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html):

> Interacting with Other User Interface Controls
>   In iOS 6.0 and later, default control actions prevent overlapping gesture recognizer behavior. For example, the default action for a button is a single tap. If you have a single tap gesture recognizer attached to a button’s parent view, and the user taps the button, then the button’s action method receives the touch event instead of the gesture recognizer. This applies only to gesture recognition that overlaps the default action for a control, which includes:
>
> A single finger single tap on a UIButton, UISwitch, UIStepper, UISegmentedControl, and UIPageControl.
>
> ...
>
> If you have a custom subclass of one of these controls and you want to change the default action, attach a gesture recognizer directly to the control instead of to the parent view. Then, the gesture recognizer receives the touch event first. As always, be sure to read the iOS Human Interface Guidelines to ensure that your app offers an intuitive user experience, especially when overriding the default behavior of a standard control.

So, it seems you can attach the gesture recogniser directly to the control (possibly you need to subclass `UIStepper` for this to work, I am not really sure how to interpret the last paragraph). Hopefully this will not disable the basic workings of the stepper (but maybe it will).

Comment: Outlet Connections, Gesture Recognizers is unselected. It doesn't appear any gesture recognizers are visible this way. I thought of using `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` but I don't know how to get a handle on the stepper's gesture recognizer.

Comment: you should inspect your UIStepper outlet programmatically to see if its `gestureRecognizers` property has any content… not from Interface Builder...

Comment: Hmmm. I'll try that. Meanwhile, I've pasted a screen shot from the profiler showing the call tree. I'm surprised I don't see anything looking like a gesture recognizer there.

Comment: `sender.gestureRecognizers` is nil (`sender` is the stepper object).

Comment: I see. Please, check my edited answer. This case is explicitly mentioned in Apple docs.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but there is a property viewFlags that includes two values, `gesturesEnabled` and `deliversTouchesForGesturesToSuperview`, both YES.

Comment: I don't think the new answer addresses my issue. I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: That `viewFlags` would let think that the superview would get touches to be handled through gesture recognisers, although it does not seem so in your tests...

Comment: In response to your edited reply, yes, the stepper, by default, responds to a longpress by updating about once a second for a while, then more frequently as time elapses. I agree that's probably what the timer is for. The technique of adding a recognizer to the control accomplishes the reverse of what I'm trying to do (getting a gesture recognizer on the parent view to fire before the control). I want the control to recognize its gesture instead of the recognizer in the parent view. I'm guessing this doesn't work because longpress is NOT the default gesture. That would match the doc you quoted

Comment: To let the stepper receive the touches, have you set the parent view gesture recogniser's `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO`?